# When I change a py module print function, it does not show up in interpreter

Tags: python

when I comment and uncomment the below print(listm) line, the change is not showing up in 3.10 interpreter on windows. It only prints the original .py code ~ I have to resave and rename the code into a new file for it to work.  Any ideas? I'm trying to write a regex script and it is annoying in testing it by constantly having to resave the file. I've tried the   del parse_sh_cdp_neighbors   and to reimport   from testing6 import parse_sh_cdp_neighbors and it won't print right unless i resave everything

```
import re

def parse_sh_cdp_neighbors(command_output):
    regex = re.compile(
    r"(?P<r_dev>\w+)  +(?P<l_intf>\S+ \S+)"
    r"  +\d+  +[\w ]+  +\S+ +(?P<r_intf>\S+ \S+)")
    
    connect_dict = {}

    with open(command_output) as f:
        eld = f.read()
        z = regex.finditer(eld)
        **listm = eld.splitlines()**
        print(listm)
```

Comment: Reimport doesn't work because modules are cached.  Look for `reload`.

Comment: Yes this worked, how do I post the question as answered? Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: @hfak you can answer your own question once you have enough reputation points